# Xcode WKWebView (IOS) Wont Load Webpage, White Screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I have searched for a few hours now and tried many solutions and none seem to work.

I have disabled my AVG web shield, added this to my plist under App transport

```
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
```

Code below

```
    let link = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")!
    let req = URLRequest(url: link)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: webView)
    self.webView!.load(req)
```

I am extremely confused why any web page does not load

I have tried http and https

I have tired multiple websites, no luck

it just stays on a blank white screen

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in my playground, so something is wrong with how you are creating the web view or the constraints.  See example:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let webView = WKWebView()
        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        let link = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")!
        let req = URLRequest(url: link)
        webView.load(req)
        view.setNeedsLayout()
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this on OSX apps and works for that go to general app settings, sandbox mode turn on and off again. Works every time for me on OSX apps

Comment: OSX apps have sandbox, IOS always has sandbox enabled you cannot disable it :/

Comment: Sorry my bad, hope you get it sorted